# Laravel 5.1 suggested relationship setup

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am building a timesheet system and have setup a model for timesheets.  Timesheet can have many rows - for example when I add a timesheet, I can add many days (rows) to the timesheet.

I want to be able to sync rows when a timesheet gets saved.  For example, new rows will be added to the database, missing rows from the given array will be removed from the database.

I understand I can use `sync` method which works like this, however, I do not think I need a `belongsToMany` relationship.  Currently I have my `row` relationship setup as a `hasMany`.  The timesheet model looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Timesheet;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Timesheet extends Model
{    
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'timesheet';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'week', 'year', 'token', 'total_hours'];

    /**
     * Define that we want to include timestamps.
     *
     * @var boolean
     */
    public $timestamps = true;

    /**
     * Boot the model.
     *
     */
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::deleting(function($timesheet)
        {
            $timesheet->row()->delete();
        });
    }

    /**
     * The rows that belong to the timesheet.
     *
     * @return Object
     */
    public function row()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Timesheet\RowTimesheet');
    }

}
```

The row_timesheet model looks like this:

```
namespace App\Models\Timesheet;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class RowTimesheet extends Model
{    
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'row_timesheet';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['timesheet_id', 'activity_category', 'description', 'eri_number', 'ewn_number'];

    /**
     * Define that we want to include timestamps.
     *
     * @var boolean
     */
    public $timestamps = true;
```

What do I need to do in order to make something like this work:

```
$this->timesheet->find($id)->row()->sync($data);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the 'sync' methods works with 'belongsTomany' relationship.
what you have is 'hasMany' relationship, for that you need to do something like below

use 'save' method instead of 'sync' for hasMany relationship

```
$data = new App\Comment(['message' => 'A new comment.']);
$this->timesheet->find($id)->row()->save($data);  // saves single row sheet object for a timesheet

$this->timesheet->find($id)->row()->saveMany($multipleData);  // saves multiple  row sheet objects for a timesheet
```